# The list of microphones when I try Microphone.list_microphone_names() is returning an empty list no microphones are being detected

Tags: python, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, pyaudio

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio as py_audio

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
Mic_list = sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
Mic_list
```

the output of the `Mic_list` above is an empty list [], no microphones are being detected.

I'm working on google colab

Answer (score 2):

As you are working on Google Colab, the `py_audio` API will look for a microphone on the machine it is currently installed. Since it is on a remote machine that likely won't have any microphone installed, you get an empty list. To record on colab, either try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272815/google-colab-audio-recording-how-to-implement-a-more-precise-way-to-tell-users), use a notebook on local, or load your pre-recorded data.